# Can you tell if a tab is iframe or fbml without being admin

Tags: iframe, fbml

I am trying to figure out a way to tell if  page is written in fbml or if it is an iframe.  Is there any way to know this without being an admin and looking at the app's code?  This could be a very obvious answer so forgive me if thats the case here.  Unfortunately google searches have not returned the info I am looking for, just tutorials on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Pretty Simple to just figure out if the tab has a custom icon its an iframe because static fbml doesnt support custom icons if u want to know just right click the app it will give u options such as view source etc.. on an fbml tab.. but on iframe it will say view IFRAME source if u want to knw jst go to the page click the tab u wanna knw abt u will see this at the end ?sk=app_6009294086

6009294086 is the application ID just go to facebook.com/APP ID
in this case it would be facebook.com/6009294086
& it will open up the application page for u if its static fbml then its facebook's app if its some other then its a custom APP.